# jQuery global object doesn't work inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any anyone tell me why the example below doesn't work:

```
var obj = $('#example');

function examplefunc(){
    obj.hide();
}
```

Whilst the second one works fine:

```
function examplefunc(){
    var obj = $('#example');

    obj.hide();
}
```

I know that the difference is obvious - in first example we have global variable, whilst in second we have local one. But yet another example shows that global string var i accessible inside the function:

```
var text = "Hello World!"

function examplefunc(){
    alert(text);
}
```

How can I make a global jQuery object variable visible inside the function in the first example? Is there any limitation of creating and using a global jQuery object? Any solutions?

Comment: There is no limitation, the first block of code you show should work. You aren't showing us all of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hazard my guess that you're executing this line of code:

```
var obj = $('#example');
```

Before the element with ID of `example` is parsed into the DOM by the browser.  You can work around it by moving your `<script>` element to below the `#example` element in your document, or you can make use of the document ready event:

```
var obj;

$(function () {  // This function is run after the document is parsed and ready
    obj = $('#example');
});

function examplefunc(){
    obj.hide();
}
```